# PHP function returns 0, not sure why

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, function

Here is the PHP im working with:

Below values from a database:

```
$quote = 49;
$add_amp = 0;
$con_array = "3,2,1";


function calcAddAmp($mul)
{
    $add_amp = $add_amp + $mul*($quote);

}


$con_array = explode(",", $con);

for($i = 0; $i < count($con_array); $i++) { 
    switch ($fun) {
        case 1:
            calcAddAmp(.01);
            break;
        case 2:
            calcAddAmp(.05);
            break;
        case 3:
            calcAddAmp(.02);
            break;
        case 4:
            calcAddAmp(.09);
            break;
    }
}



$quote = $quote + $add_amp;
```

The issue is seen here:

```
echo $add_amp;
```

$add_amp returns 0, which makes $quote the same value as before, 49.

```
echo $quote;
```

I'm sure I am just writing this function incorrectly, but I can't find where I went wrong.

Comment: `$add_amp` does not "return" anything. It is not a function.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: Every function in PHP returns something, if only it’s an implicit `null` value.

Comment: @Gumbo: `$add_amp` is a variable, not a function.

Comment: Even if the variable `$add_amp` inside the function would not be bound to the function scope, you’re not reassigning `$quote` anywhere.

Comment: @Gumbo: I don't understand what you're trying to say, sorry.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: Oh, now I see it. I thought you wouldn’t want to call it a function because [mathematic functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_\(mathematics\)) do always have an output value. Well, I think I should better go to sleep … :)

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: What I meant is: “[If the `return()` is omitted the value NULL will be returned.](http://php.net/functions.returning-values)”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables have *function scope*. Setting `$add_amp` inside a function does not automatically modify the variable by the same name outside the function. If you don't `return` the value from the function it's pointless. I'd simplify this whole unnecessary `switch`/`function` to this though:

```
$multipliers = array(1 => .01, 2 => .05, 3 => .02, 4 => .09);

foreach ($con_array as $con) {
    $add_amp += $multipliers[$con] * $quote;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that the switch function is not necessary. This is very useful

Answer (score 1):

`$add_amp` is declared outside of your function.

If you want to modify the global one, you need to change your function like this:

```
function calcAddAmp($mul)
{     
    global $quote;
    global $add_amp;
    $add_amp = $add_amp + $mul * $quote;
}
```

It would be even better to just return the value from your function:

```
function calcAddAmp($mul,$a,$q)
{
    return $a + $mul * $q;
}

$add_amp = calcAddAmp(0.5,$add_amp,$quote);
```

Comment: @joakim: Why's that? The entire point of the second example is that it does not use globals.

Comment: @joakimdahlstrom: No, the second method avoids using global variables, which makes it a better way to do this. Instead the required variables are passed as an argument. Makes it a lot easier to maintain the code, because it has no side effects.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal Oh haha, he just changed the function, it was incomplete before.

Comment: Yeah, it's different now from when I commented on it.

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($con_array); $i++) { 
    switch ($fun) {
```

I think you meant:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($con_array); $i++) { 
    switch ($con_array[$i]) {
```

Otherwise your cases never match (as `$fun` doesn't exist), `calcAddAmp` is never called and `$add_amp`'s value never changes.

---

You will also need to be sure to use the *global* `$add_amp` and `$quote` in `calcAddAmp`, as [at the moment you're operating on some new local ones](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) with the same name:

```
function calcAddAmp($mul) {
   global $add_amp, $quote;
   $add_amp += $mul * $quote;
}
```

or

```
function calcAddAmp($mul) {
   $GLOBALS['add_amp'] += $mul * $GLOBALS['quote'];
}
```

It would be better to avoid globals entirely, and pass these variables where they are required as function parameters.

Comment: `$quote` also needs to be global, in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Use the global keyword in the function. And your switch is wrong $fun is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

The `$add_amp` is a local variable in the function. It will be reassigned every time you call the function, and the `$add_amp` variable that you created at the top will always be 0.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach, by using reference:

```
function calcAddAmp(&$add_amp, $mul)
{
    global $quote;

    $add_amp += $mul*($quote);
}
```

example of usage:

```
calcAddAmp($add_amp, 0.5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Quote and add_amp need to be global.

```
global $quote;
global $add_amp;

$quote = 49;
$add_amp = 0;
$con_array = "3,2,1";


function calcAddAmp($mul)
{
    global $quote;
    global $add_amp;

    $add_amp = $add_amp + $mul*($quote);

}
```